# Trimming the XML file

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a XML file as shown below

```
<NewDataSet>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>1</C> 
  <M /> 
  </T>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>1</C> 
  <M /> 
  </T>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>1</C> 
  <M /> 
  </T>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>1</C> 
  <M /> 
  </T>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>2</C> 
  <M>44</M> 
  </T>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>2</C> 
  <M>45</M> 
  </T>
- <T>
  <P /> 
  <C>2</C> 
  <M>46</M> 
  </T>
</NewDataSet>
```

Question - Basicall i should remove the block

```
<T>
  <P /> 
  <C>1</C> 
  <M /> 
  </T>
```

that does not have `<M>` Value

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. Do you want to save the output or just return the T elements that have no M values for display?

Comment: Basically i want to trim down this xml file by deleting the T tag and its child tags which does not have value in M Tag

Answer (score 1):

Load the whole document into an `XmlDocument` (or `XDocument`), select nodes with an XPath like `/T[not(./M)]` and delete them.

Comment: I am using DotNet 2.0 framework can you please help me with a code

Comment: XmlDocument is a .Net 2.0 class, please look it up on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look into [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

You could query for all XElements containing an empty M Element, and remove those from their parent XML Element.

Take for example:

```
from element in _yourXDocument.Descendants("NewDataSet")
select element
where element.Descendants("M").Value = String.Empty;
```

For .Net 2.0, use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Comment: Ow crap, no it won't :(. Sorry, I was assuming you were using .Net 3.5